# Unable to mount Time Capsule from a Macbook when backups work

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, mount

I have two Macbooks (`A` and `B`). `A` backs-up to Time Capsule (`TC`), while `B` does not. I used to mount `TC` and move files there, which I don't want to keep on `A` or `B`.

Few weeks ago it became impossible to mount `TC` on `A`, while `B` is still mounting fine. `A` continues to do backups to `TC` as usual. `A` does not show `TC` in left sidebar in Finder (`B` does), but one can find it via Networks. Trying to connect to partition takes forever. The partition is showed as mounted, however, `/Volumes/` does not have it so as Disk Utility.

I restarted both `TC` and `A`, but the problem persists. Is there anything else I can reset to solve this issue?

Buttons to unmount and to "connect as..." do not respond:

[image: hanging]

```
$ df -g
Filesystem    1G-blocks Used Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1          232  226         5    98% 59416761 1564485   97%   /
devfs                 0    0         0   100%      696       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts            0    0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home         0    0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /home
$
```

Comment: It looks like some comments are deleted, so I've moved this conversation [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30887/discussion-on-question-by-andrei-unable-to-mount-time-capsule-from-a-macbook-whe) so that the clarifications can make sense and not confuse the wording of the question as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Re-adding the Time Capsule to Time Machine may work

I used to face problems with the mount. Removing the Time Capsule (`TC`) from `A`'s Time Machine and re-adding helped.

Otherwise, the obvious ultimate solution would be to remove the `A`'s backup from TC completely and take a fresh backup.

Comment: All these rather risky manipulations should only be attempted within a perfectly working network. And this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Hm, I hope I won't loose the old backups removing `TC` from `A`? I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Network seems working fine. I have 3 macbooks and 4 phones using it without noticeable issues. All of them are connected to `TC` directly.

Comment: @Andrei: how do you explain `A` can't access `TC`? Could you check a basic `ping` to check it is really working?

Comment: @danielAzuelos `B` can mount `TC`. `A` shows `TC` as already mounted. I haven't had a chance to remove `TC` from `A` yet. Maybe today

Comment: @sdayal I've just tried to remove backup disk from `A` Time Machine and added it again. It asked password and set up fine, but the mounting is still hanging. I've added screenshot showing it. I will try to remove-n-restart to see if it helps.

Comment: @Andrei: how is your disk secured? Of the 3 options: a) With Accounts, b) With a disk password c) With a device password, I have selected "With a Disk Password". And I have selected "Remember this password in KeyChain"

Comment: @sdayal I have installed El Capitan update and the issue was resolved. I hope it ain't coming back because I ran out of system updates atm :)

Comment: Awesome! I'm so happy that you could get it working :)